# How to verify every single protected route with JWT on React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios, jwt

I've just setup the JWT authentication on backend/frontend. But my I'm wondering what's the best practice to verify the token when accessing protected routes...

I wrote a function that sends a GET Request with the token to the server via axios. Should I include this function on every single page and trigger the GET Request every time It renders a protected route?

By the way this is the function that verifies the token:

````
  const isAuth = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/admin", {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "auth-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  };```
````

Comment: IMO I would use context to store the response from the jwt verification.  This way you wouldn't be constantly pinging your back end to verify the jwt

Comment: But as soon as you close the tab, you lose the state. Next time you need to login over and over again. Am I right?